# ant parallel to mark build success

Tags: ant

I am using ANT parallel task to timeout after starting a server. At the timeout ant returns build failure. I want build to be successful after timeout seconds. Please find the below code.

```
<target name="tomcat-start">
    <parallel threadCount="1" timeout="30000" failonany="true">
  <sshexec host="10.0.19.47"
    trust="true"
  username="${server_username}"
  password="${server_password}"
  command="nohup java -jar /home/techteam/TravelSecure-deployments/DTCMWS_TravelSecure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &amp; disown" />
  <echo> Microsite service started successfully. Please wait for service to start running</echo>
  </parallel>
  </target>
```

Comment: after the 30sec ends for the timout, does the server starts?

Comment: Yes the server starts